# Eigenvalues of powered matrices $A^3$ and $A^3 - 5I$

Tags: linear-algebra

[Question part A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmGng.png)

[Question Part B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiUKk.png)

Im not too sure how to go about this question, I just multiplied the matrix by itself three times and then solved for eigenvalues that way, for part B I'm lost as to how to express it, something along the lines of $A^4 = 2A^3 = 4A^2 $ etc. hoping anyone could shed some light onto how to go about this

Answer (score 3):

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $1,1,1,3$ with multiplicity !

Part A:

If $ \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $ \lambda^3$ is an eigenvalue of $A^3$ and $\lambda^3-5$ is an eigenvalue of $A^3-5I.$

Part B: the characteristic polynomial $p$ of $A$  is

$$ p(x)=(x-1)^3(x-3).$$

Cayley Hamilton gives: $p(A)=0.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: The question states without multiplicity thought does that not make the answer 1,27